# Need to scrape a webpage using BeautifulSoup and find data rich nodes especially tables using python

Tags: python-2.7, tags, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following code, but it is giving me an error.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://www.amazon.com/Harry-Potter-And-Chamber-Secrets/dp/0439064872/ref=pd_bxgy_b_img_y"
r = requests.get(url)
html = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
links = html.find("table",{"class":"bucket"}).find_all("h2",{"class":"content"})

print links
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/pgadmin/Google Drive/share sem2/SEMINAR/4.py", line 52, in <module>
    links = html.find("table",{"class":"bucket"}).find_all("h2",{"class":"content"})
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

I am trying to get the data into the bucket class.

Comment: You are getting that error because there is no `table` element with a `bucket` class on the page you are scraping, so because that is not found, it returns `None`. `None` has no method `find_all` obviously. You might want to check which element with the class `bucket` you are really looking for and update your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In general we try to avoid writing in all caps when asking questions here. I've edited your question to no longer include all caps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag is incorrect. Your desired data is inside a `td` tag. Use it like this:

```
bucket = html.find("td", attrs={"class":"bucket"})
links = [a.get('href') for a in bucket.find_all('a')]
```